# how to show data in datalist in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am quite newbie to WPF.I was just wondering if there is any control in wpf like repeater control in asp.net. I want to use a template to display my collection and want to display in order like left to right And top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of laying out a collection of items.

I would suggest taking a look at the ListView and ItemsControl.  You style the template for your content to display the data how you want.

To Answer your question you can set the items panel to a panel that will allow you to choose direction ie:

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: How can set direction and repeat columns in listview and itemsControl.